# SQL Query to include future dated records

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

per_all_assignments_m is date effective and has the following sample data -

```
effective_start_date                effective_end_date                  ASG_Name
01-01-2020                              31-12-4712                      Sam
02-03-2020                              31-12-4712                      Maz
08-08-2020                              31-12-4712                      Fis
07-01-2020                              20-02-2020                      Max
```

When i use the below query it gives me the output as of today -

```
select ASG_Name from per_all_assignments_m
where trunc(sysdate) between effective_start_date and effective_end_date
```

This gives me the output-

```
effective_start_date                effective_end_date                  ASG_Name
01-01-2020                              31-12-4712                      Sam
02-03-2020                              31-12-4712                      Maz
```

How can i modify it in a way that it also includes data i.e. >=trunc(sysdate) i.e. the output should look like -

```
effective_start_date                effective_end_date                  ASG_Name
01-01-2020                              31-12-4712                      Sam
02-03-2020                              31-12-4712                      Maz
08-08-2020                              31-12-4712                      Fis
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want a simple comparison on the end date:

```
select ASG_Name
from per_all_assignments_m
where effective_end_date > trunc(sysdate)
```